# Get Data from Firestore before Schedule a Cloud Function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble getting the data from a document and use a single field from that document as a parameter of my schedule Cloud Function, first I am trying to get the document, then call the getData() function and use that variable to call the .data out of it and i am calling the .get() with a await, still i get this error.

> Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Promise>'.

And I cannot call `await getData();` because I get this error

> Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'esnext' or 'system', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.

Any way around this? I need first get the data that contains the day of the month in which I will run the schedule function.

this is my code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

/// Get the config data for schedule time and debt payment
async function getData() {
  return await admin.firestore().doc("neighbors/0000_admin").get();
}

const configData = getData();

/// Updates the debt for each neighbor on a specific day of each month
export const debtUpdatePerMonth = functions.pubsub
  .schedule(`${configData?.data()?.day_of_month_to_pay} of month 06:00`)
  .onRun(async (context) => {

    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("neighbors")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          return doc.ref.update({
            debt: doc.data()?.debt + configData?.data()?.monthly_pay,
          });
        });
      });
  });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have two calls to `getData()` in your code, one at the top-level and one inside the function.  They are both trying to assign to the same named variable.  That's confusing to me.  The error message can't possibly be referring to either one of them as shown.  Can you clarify why you need two calls, especially the one at the top level outside the function?

Comment: Sorry Doug that is my bad, the getData() call inside of my schedule was the first try and I forgot to remove it, actually the call inside of my schedule do works and I can get the data I need there, but because I am getting two pieces of information one used in `debt: doc.data()?.debt + configData?.data()?.monthly_pay,` and the other it is supposed to be used as a day of month in: ` .schedule(`${configData?.data()?.day_of_month_to_pay} of month 06:00`)` , that is why  I was trying to call it before the schedule, I just forgot to delete the one inside, I will edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to declare a Cloud Function based on dynamically loaded data, as you are trying to do here:

```
/// Get the config data for schedule time and debt payment
async function getData() {
  return await admin.firestore().doc("neighbors/0000_admin").get();
}

const configData = getData();

/// Updates the debt for each neighbor on a specific day of each month
export const debtUpdatePerMonth = functions.pubsub
  .schedule(`${configData?.data()?.day_of_month_to_pay} of month 06:00`)
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    ...
```

The schedule that triggers a Cloud Function must be known at deploy time.

What you're trying to do can be accomplished by using Cloud Tasks. What is now your main called would be a callable (or HTTPS) function that code then schedules the Cloud Tasks. These Cloud Tasks then call your current `onRun` function.

Doug wrote a great blog post about this: [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)

Comment: Thanks Frank! that is a new subject to me I will dive in that document :)

Comment: Another question related, is there an option to run a schedule function inside on a onWrite trigger function? for example if a field of a document change then program schedule a new function with that field change?, so is there an option to call a function inside another function? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to dynamically schedule a Cloud Function, you'll need to take the approach with Cloud Tasks. I sometimes do a short delay (up to 60 seconds) by a simple `setTimeout()` in my code, but wouldn't necessarily recommend that (as you end up paying for the time when nothing is happening).